# Sequence problem with common difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem with one sequence word problem. 
You add $1000$ to your bank account and withdraw $62$ the first year, and withdraw $4$ more every year than the year before. I have to find how much am I left after $20$ years.
So I have $1000$ as a first term. But I don't get it how to write the common difference part and the recurrence system and obviously solve the problem at the end.

Comment: Forget about the $1000$ for a while, and concentrate on the withdrawals, $62, 66, 70,\dots$. You are presumably interested in the sum $62+66+\cdots +(62+(n-1)(4))$.

Comment: OH yeah BTW i forgot to tell that i need to find how much money do i have left in 20 years

Comment: You know how to compute the sum of an arithmetic progression. We could also set up the problem as a recurrence, that is less "elementary," in the sense it is usually done much later than sums of arithmetic progressions.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I dont know why but i tried to something to 1000. I had to make 62 the first term +3 the common difference and 20 the number of terms. Finally substitute number into formula.

S=0.5n(2a+(n-1)d)